# EB CLI with and AWS CLI doesn't recognize SSO sso_start_url and sso_region configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, single-sign-on, aws-cli, ebcli

I installed `EB CLI` following [these instructions](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup).

To use it, I configured `AWS CLI` for [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html#sso-configure-profile-token-auto-sso).

This creates a config file in `~/.aws/config` with these contents:

```
[profile <profile_name>]
sso_session = <session_name>
sso_account_id = <account_no>
sso_role_name = <role_name>
region = <region>
output = json
[sso-session <session_name>]
sso_start_url = <start_url>
sso_region = <region>
sso_registration_scopes = <scopes>
```

All the values seem to be correct.

Once configured, I can login using `SSO` using:

```
aws sso login --profile <profile_name>
```

This redirects me to the SSO `<start_url>` and I get the confirmation for login:

```
Successfully logged into Start URL: <start_url>
```

`EB CLI` is supposed to be able to login using the authentication methods set with `AWS CLI`. I am trying to do so with:

```
eb init --profile <profile_name>
```

However, after selecting the region, I get this error:

```
ERROR: InvalidConfigError - The profile "<profile_name>" is configured to use SSO but is missing required configuration: sso_start_url, sso_region
```

I am not sure what I am missing as the `~/.aws/config` file seems to be properly set with the `sso_start_url` and `sso_region` I specified in the `AWS CLI` configuration.

Is there any other intermediate step to get EB CLI working with `SSO`?

Comment: I copied the sso related lines into the profile section of the config file:

`sso_start_url = <start_url>
sso_region = <region>`

But now I am getting this error:

`2022-12-25 14:01:03,948 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
ERROR: SSOTokenLoadError - Error loading SSO Token: The SSO access token has either expired or is otherwise invalid.`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, but with `boto3`, not EB. Same error message though, in my Python script when I created a client. I realised that in the virtual environment, I hadn't updated `boto3` in two years. When I updated it, it worked. Try updating your EB CLI or `boto3` if you have that.

Comment: Good thought, but it didn't solve the problem with EB CLI. I'm on the latest version, 3.20.5.